# Windows explorer connect to FTP through CMD

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer

I want to connect to FTP in the Windows Explorer like:

```
CMD> explorer ftp://example.com
```

This works but prompts the username and password.

Is there a way to automatically fill these in? I want to skip these prompts.

[Windows Explorer Command-Line Options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use address in this format

```
ftp://username:password@example.com
```

You may also use `ftp -s:yourcommands.txt` command in command line. Look at `ftp /?` for more info.

Comment: That works but my password has an `@` in it :(, any way around that?

Comment: @janw Try replacing `@` in the password with the hexadecimal [escaped value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), i.e. `%40`.

Comment: That works tnx case closed